# How to 'Fade' normal material in THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, scene

I was working on fading from one area to another while using THREE.JS

So far I have developed a technique i really like that involves using the fog of the scene, and increasing its density until everything disappears, and then fading it out after all the scene changes are done.

This has worked very well and gives a really nice feel to the fade (rather then using something like a black 'curtain' that covers the entire screen) however, the biggest problem with it is that the normal materials don't fade with the rest of the scene.

I think I am going to have to use something like the black curtain, unless there is another technique that somebody knows of. I would be happy to provide code if its necessary, but I feel like this question doesn't require it.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Isn't the fog method expensive? I'm sure changes in fog density get sent through the pipeline.

Comment: @Neil I'm sure it is. To me its just the most elegant. It feels like you are being consumed by the darkness around you, rather then  just having a screen fall over the front of the game...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a 'Fading function' that would make all objects move to 0 opacity... Looks great!